# is the location of ros.key in http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian incorrect?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the wiki page
http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian
has an incorrect location for ros.key

s

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221472/is-the-location-of-ros.key-in-http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/installation/debian-incorrect?/) by [btsimonh](https://answers.ros.org/users/25169/btsimonh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-11-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the correct key setup command is now:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116
```

I've updated the install wiki you mentioned to reflect this.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2